# Bash recursive script gets very slow

Tags: bash, performance, recursion

I have written a script to get all child processes started from a certain process with a given string "mystring.sh" on a set of nodes given in nodefile.dat. The script works, but gets really slow after a couple of iterations. Any explanation or suggestion, how to improve it. I'm using the script to check computations on a HPC.

---

```
!/bin/bash
PID=$1;
Iter=1;
ChildPIDs=""

function getcpid() {
    cpids=($(ssh $2 "pgrep -P $1|xargs"))
    #echo "cpids=$cpids"
    #sleep 1
    Iter=(${Iter[@]} ${Iter[@]});
    ChildPIDs=(${ChildPIDs[@]} ${cpids[@]})
    for cpid in $cpids;
    do
        #echo "$cpid"
        Iter=$(($Iter+1))
        #echo $Iter
        #if [ $Iter -ge 20 ]; then break; fi
        getcpid $cpid $2
    done
}

for Server in $(cat nodefile.dat); do
  for PID in $(ssh $Server "ps -fu user | grep 'mystring.sh' | awk {'print \$2'}"); do
    getcpid $PID $Server
    if [ -z "$ChildPIDs" ]; then
      echo $PID starts no process on $Server
    else
      echo $PID starts processes ${ChildPIDs[@]} on $Server
    fi
    unset ChildPIDs
  done
done
```

---

Comment: Fix your shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: It's slow because you are constantly (re)connecting to a remote host. `getcpid` should run entirely on the remote host.

Comment: Beware!  Bash has a limited stack size that you will run into with recursion.  You will literally get a stack overflow when you hit something like a stack depth of 62 calls.  This may or may not be deep enough depending on how your processes spawn each other.

Comment: The size of the `Iter` array doubles every time `getcpid` runs -- so after 10 runs it has has 1,024 entries, and after 20 iterations it has 1,048,576, etc. You're also using `cpids` inconsistently -- creating it as an array, then referencing it as a plain variable. Also, the number of `ssh` connections is blown way up running a separate connection for each and every process, rather than supplying a comma-separated list to `pgrep -P` to get an entire level at once.